# Why is logistic regression called regression?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, logistic-regression

According to what I have understood, linear regression predicts the outcome which can have continuous values, whereas logistic regression predicts outcome which is discrete. It seems to me that logistic regression is similar to a classification problem. So, why is it called *regression*?

There is also a related question: [What is the difference between linear regression and logistic regression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12146914/3924118)

Comment: `logistic regression` is in fact a classification strategy. So its name can be confusing. Why is it called logistic "regression"? Good question - maybe because from the statistics view it's just a generalized linear model that predicts continuous values between `0` and `1`, which can be interpreted as `probabilities`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. There is [Stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com) for this type of questions.

Comment: If this question is off-topic, then isn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146914/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression off-topic too? There are many questions on this site about python libraries performing logistic regression because it is difficult to separate implementation questions from theoretical questions like this one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a strict link between linear regression and logistic regression.

With linear regression you're looking for the k<sub>i</sub> parameters:

> h = k<sub>0</sub> + Σ k<sub>i</sub> ˙ X<sub>i</sub> = K<sup>t</sup> ˙ X

With logistic regression you've the same aim but the equation is:

> h = g(K<sup>t</sup> ˙ X)

Where `g` is the [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function):

> g(w) = 1 / (1 + e<sup>-w</sup>)

So:

> h = 1 / (1 + e<sup>-K<sup>t</sup> ˙ X</sup>)

and you need to fit K to your data.

Assuming a binary classification problem, the output `h` is the estimated probability that the example `x` is a positive match in the classification task:

> P(Y = 1) = 1 / (1 + e<sup>-K<sup>t</sup> ˙ X</sup>)

When the probability is greater than 0.5 then we can predict "a match".

The probability is greater than 0.5 when:

> g(w) > 0.5

and this is true when:

> w = K<sup>t</sup> ˙ X ≥ 0

The hyperplane:

> K<sup>t</sup> ˙ X = 0

is the decision boundary.

In summary:

- logistic regression is a generalized linear model using the same basic formula of linear regression but it is [regressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) for the probability of a categorical outcome.

This is a very abridged version. You can find a simple explanation in [these videos](https://class.coursera.org/ml-003/lecture) (third week of *Machine Learning* by Andrew Ng).

You can also take a look at http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/06_Logistic_Regression.html for some notes on the lessons.

Answer (score 3):

As explained earlier,logistic regression is a generalized linear model using the same basic formula of linear regression but it is regressing for the probability of a categorical outcome.

[image: 12]

As you can see, we get similar type of equation for both linear and logistic regression. 
Difference lies in fact that linear regression give continous values of y for given x where logistic regression also gives continous values of p(y=1) for given x which is coverted later to y=0 or y=1 based on threshold value(0.5).

[image: 21]

Answer (score 1):

Logistic regression falls under the category of supervised learning.It measures the relationship between categorical dependent variable and one or more independent variables by estimating probabilities using logistic/sigmoid function.
Logistic regression is a bit similar to linear regression or we can see it as a generalized linear model.
In linear regression we predict output y based on a weighted sum of input variables.

y=c+ x1*w1 + x2*w2 + x3*w3 + .....+ xn*wn

The main purpose of linear regression is to estimate values of c,w1,w2,...,wn and minimize the cost function and predict y.

Logistic regression also does the same thing but with one addition. It pass the result through a special function called logistic/sigmoid function to produce the output y.

y=logistic(c + x1*w1 + x2*w2 + x3*w3 + ....+ xn*wn)

y=1/1+e[-(c + x1*w1 + x2*w2 + x3*w3 + ....+ xn*wn)]