# Analysis of regression algorithms on matlab environment

Tags: matlab, regression, svm, linear-regression, logistic-regression

Hi I want to do a comprehensive analysis of regression techniques and so will go on editing this question. I am trying to solve a regression problem using techniques available in Matlab. Ideally I would like to look at techniques such as

1. Linear Regression
2. Logistic Regression
3. Bayesian Regression
4. Support Vector Regression
5. Gaussian Process for Regression

### Problem Statement

Given the data `X` and `Y` of size `333x128` and `333x1` where `333` is the number of training examples and `128` is the feature dimensions. The problem I am solving is an regression one and **not a classification one**.  I intend to do all of the above in Matlab.

---

### Linear Regression

The code for Linear Regression is given as follows : It takes the input data from the "hald" dataset and takes the first 10 elements for training purposes and the next 3 elements for testing purposes. The last line prints the output
i.e., the predicted values and the actual labels.

```
clc; clear all; close all;
load hald
X = ingredients; % Predictor variables
y = heat; % Response
mdl = fitlm(X(1:10,:),y(1:10,:));
predicted_values = feval(mdl,X(11:end,:));
[y(11:end,:) predicted_values]
```

The output is given as :

```
ans =
   83.8000   80.2845
  113.3000  112.8545
  109.4000  112.5293
```

However can anyone explain to me what is meant by Generalized Linear Regression Model ? In matlab, there are two commands specifically for this : [glmfit](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/glmfit.html)/[glmval](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/glmval.html) and [fitglm](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitglm.html#inputarg_modelspec)/[feval](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/generalizedlinearmodel.feval.html).

The code for applying the generalized linear regreesion model is given below:

```
mdl = fitglm(X(1:10,:),y(1:10,:),'quadratic');
predicted_values = feval(mdl,X(11:end,:));
error = sum((y(11:end,:)-predicted_values).^2)

[b, dev] = glmfit(X(1:10,:),y(1:10,:),'normal','link','identity');
predicted_values = glmval(b,X(11:end,:),'identity');
error = sum((y(11:end,:)-predicted_values).^2)
```

**What is the difference between the two operations ?**

Also `glmfit` has a term called `distr` and `link`. What does this distribution mean ? How to choose the best distribution ? For the above example, based only on the data how does one estimate the distribution apriori?

Also as I understand the link function is used to establish a link between the linear model and the response variables. Does it mean that logistic regression is a subset of generalized linear regression model? I read through the details at [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) but could not clear my doubts.

---

### Support Vector Regression

The code for Linear Regression is given as follows : Here I have the option to standardize the data. The kernel I have choosen is the rbf kernel with auto scale. Many options like polynomial kernel, gaussian kernel, linear, etc are also available.

```
mdl = fitrsvm(X(1:10,:),y(1:10,:),'KernelFunction','rbf','KernelScale','auto','Standardize',true);    
predicted_values = predict(mdl,X(11:end,:));
```

---

### Logistic Regression

I am unable to use logistic regression to solve this regression problem. I have through various sources and always they have solved the classification problem but my label space is continuous and not discrete. In this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression)it is explicitly stated that **As such it is not a classification method**. However
based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499018/difference-between-linear-and-logistic-regression-why-is-logistic-regression-ca) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146914/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression) it seems to me that **logistic regression can only be used for classification ?**

I have also gone through the [mnrfit](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrfit.html)/[mnrval](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrval.html) tutorials but there also they deal with classification problems.

Please provide a small example based on my above data to show how logistic regression can be used for regression ?

Comment: Great question ! I'll try to give some feedback as well

Comment: I will also try to address things. Yet don't you think this question fits better to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Drazick maybe but I wanted to know about the different implementation scenarios in Matlab