# Linear regression when the dependent is nominal

Tags: analytics, linear-regression

[image: Dataset with a dependent variable fo Type_of_Sacrum]

I analysed the following data sample using SPSS, to find if there is any relationship between the dependent variable of (Type_of_Sacrum) and the independent variables of (Sex, S.weight, S.length, S.width and Body_Mass). 
I used Chi-Squared model for (Type_of_Sacrum and Sex). I also used linear regression for (Type_of_Sacrum and S.weight, S.length, S.width and Body_Mass). I am not sure if i am doing the right thing specially that the dependent variable (Type_of_Sacrum) is nominal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a statistics question not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear Regression is usually carried out when your dependent variable is a continuous variable.(https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/continuous-variable/)

Since your dependent variable comes across as categorical, you may want to look at performing Logistic Regression.
You can find some reference on [What is the difference between linear regression and logistic regression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146914/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression)